# Android app removed due to vulnerable to Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-security

We found that your app contains security vulnerabilities, which can expose user information or damage a user’s device. This is a violation of Device and Network Abuse policy. Specifically, your app(s) are vulnerable to Apache Cordova (CVE-2015-5256, CVE-2015-1835).

My app was removed from Google play store with above warning but my app is in native android code. And i m not using anything related to cordova then why i m getting this error. Has anybody faced same problem ?

Comment: Also consider any libraries your application ships with.

Comment: This has to be a mistake. These vulnerabilities are quite old and about very old versions of Cordova...